# How to transform in python a string list into a json with a proper format?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a list of values which shall end up in a specific json format.

**example input:**

```
plate_list = "TestXX105,TestXX106"
```

**example output:**

```
plate_json = '[{"key": "plate1", "value": "TestXX103"}, {"key":
"plate2", "value": "TestXX104"}]'
```

I tried to generate a dataframe and transform it into a json, but the formatting never fit:

```
plate_Barcodes = pd.DataFrame()

plate_list = "TestXX105,TestXX106"
 
plate_count = "plate1,plate2"

plate_Barcodes["key"] = pd.Series(plate_count.split(","))
 
plate_Barcodes["value"] = pd.Series(plate_list.split(","))
 
result = plate_Barcodes.to_json(orient = "columns")
```

But the result always includes the index: `{"key":{"0":"TestXX105","1":"TestXX106"},"value":{"0":"TestXX105","1":"TestXX106"}}`

Do you have an idea, how I could receive my needed format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `orient = records` instead.

```
plate_Barcodes.to_json(orient = "records")
#'[{"key":"plate1","value":"TestXX105"},{"key":"plate2","value":"TestXX106"}]'
```

You can read more about `orient` and the options -> outputs it provides in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html#pandas-dataframe-to-json).